# Is it possible to prevent your app from appearing as an extension for specific apps?

Tags: ios8

I've built an Action Extension for my app, and when i choose to Open In... something from inside of my app, I appear as an extension for myself. This UX is kinda weird, but also, it doesnt even work when i try to be an extension of myself.

I dont see anything in the documentation that specifies responding apps aside from NSExtensionActivationRule?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment in iOS 8.0